# Weblogic 10.3 classloader issue

Tags: java, maven, classpath, weblogic-10.x, maven-war-plugin

**Summary**

Application of which has not structurally changed or any code change, is now experiencing classpath issues. Only thing that has changed is the environment of which it was built in (new solaris box).

Application server: weblogic 10.3

Maven-war-plugin: 2.3

**The error**

Within the application war are 2 dependencies of which have different versions of the same class, one version missing a certain constructor...you can see where this is going. We are getting a runtime error, because the wrong version of the class (missing the constructor) is being targeted.

Now this is a maven project and the dependencies are ordered in such a way that the correct version of this class will appear on the classpath first at time of compiling.

As far as we are aware right now, all that has changed is the new build box, of which the build department build the war file on.

**Testing done**

If I create the war on my own local environment (windows) and deploy it to the weblogic environment server (unix box), no issue.

However when it is built on the build box (solaris) and I then deploy it to the same environment, I get the issue.

I have compared the two war files and find no differences.

To confirm what I suspected (hitting the wrong class first on the classpath) I built the package excluding the wrong version, and the surprise surprise it works. The weblogic classloader is clearly loading this incorrect class before the other.

Issue still being, I need to identify the cause of this to now happen suddenly.

**Question**

What are the rules for weblogic's classloader, in terms of deciding which dependency in lib is loaded first?

And how is it possible that this behaviour could have changed between two different wars which are exactly the same except for the version number in the MANIFEST?

Many thanks,

**User Edit**

As requested the Maven Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.xxx.web:adminapp:war:100462.7
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- struts:struts:jar:1.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile (version managed from 2.0)
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl104-over-slf4j:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:request:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile (version managed from 1.5)
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.xxx.busservices:cdm:jar:623377.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.busservices:homeratingservice-java-client:jar:1011147.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.busservices:motorratingservice-java-client:jar:1011147.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.techservices:entrefdata-java-client:jar:1011147.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.techservices:auditservice-java-client:jar:626434.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.framework:framework:jar:626434.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.xxx.ibis:xxx-logging:jar:956942.1:compile
[INFO] +- weblogic:wlfullclient:jar:10.3:provided
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
```

The `cdm.jar` contains a class called FactorValueLite which is the correct version and within the `motorratingservice-java-client.jar` also exists this class which is the wrong version, this jar appears to be getting loaded onto the classpath first.

Comment: Can you exclude the dependency which you know to contain the class in error from your build using dependecy/exclusions...? If you can't perhaps http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/ can help.

Comment: I have done this, to prove that this is the issue, but why all of a sudden this is now an issue is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Have you compared the versions of the JVMs in both envs?  Can only suspect they perform classpath searching in different ways.

Comment: Well I am ruling that out, as currently, I have two versions of the source code built now in the same manner (through jenkins) the only difference is the version number and one of them works, the other doesnt. Both running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have stale artifacts in your local repositories (on the machine you're building) where it's failing.

Try to either remove it, or specify a different path (just for the sake of testing). For example:

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/repository
```

If that passes, then the fix is simple: remove the repository.

Comment: I have compared the checksum on the artifacts within both the working war and the one not working and both are exactly the same.

Comment: Please, provide some more information regarding the class that has a `NoSuchMethodError` (provide name, artifact in which it's found, etc). Also, attach a `mvn dependency:tree` of the project building the war artifact.

Comment: Is there a difference in the libraries that are part of the web app containers on the hosts you're deploying the artifact to?

Comment: there is no shared library on weblogic involving these classes.

Comment: Ok, so try putting the `cdm` dependency as your very first `<dependency/>` in your `<dependencies/>` section. I doubt this will solve it, but try it just for kicks. Alternatively, simply remove the duplicated class from the `motorratingservice-java-client` dependency. If the `motorratingservice-java-client` is a shaded jar, perhaps you might want to update it's dependency to the artifact which contains the class (unless it's directly in that jar).

Comment: I already have `cdm` as the first dependency, hence avoiding this issue at compile time. To prove this was the case I removed the class from `motorratingservice-java-client` and it works, so obviously picking up the `cdm` class. What is baffling me is what has triggered this to start happening, and if I package the jar from windows it doesnt happen at runtime, how this affects weblogic classloader I cannot find any info.

Comment: This is weird indeed. Could you not remove the class from the `motorratingservice-java-client` artifact? Is that artifact actually necessary? Maybe you could have it with scope `provided`, or something (if you can't remove the class). Perhaps you could extract the class into a separate module and remove it from both modules and add a dependency to the artifact you've moved it...?

Comment: ye, there are various ways I could overcome it, what I am looking to do is completely remove the class from `motorratingservice-java-client` dependency, just means lots of regression testing before implementation. I was more so curious as to what has caused this dorment issue if you like to come to light now.

Comment: It may well be the case that there is some `Set` or `Map` that is used to store the list of dependencies when they are parsed from the `pom.xml` before being returned as a `List`. If this is the case, you can expect such unpredicted/unordered results and that could explain the behavior. I suggest simply removing the class from the problematic artifact and either creating a new module for it (and removing it from both artifacts), or adding a dependency to the other artifact which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL `Class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` ("file:jar:...") to the used jar. My guess is different jars one in the application server's lib directory.